# What would seats look like for centaurs?

Tags: centaur

While designing seats for humans are relatively simple, trying to figure one out for a centaur isn't all that easy. These centaurs are as you'd expect, horses with a human torso in the place of their head with human arms on that torso. These seats have to be easy to move around & use for a variety of purposes, they need to be able to fit into any role a chair for a normal human could be used for. However they don't need to be able to be made easily. These centaurs come into existence *well* after modern manufacturing technology has been developed. So it can require whatever fancy machinery that exists today, it doesn't need to be able to be made by a carpenter with basic tools. What design of chair could work for centaurs with these requirements?

Comment: Toilets aren't movable. And you don't have to sit on it for it to be a [toilet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squat_toilet). Chair designs and toilet designs can be different.

Comment: @MichaelKutz that was a leftover bit of text i forgot to remove

Comment: They don't need to sit in the proper sense of the term. Horses are even capable of [sleep while standing](https://ihearthorses.com/7-facts-you-should-know-about-how-horses-sleep/)

Comment: Are you looking for a toilet design AND a chair design?

Comment: @MichaelKutz that was a leftover bit of text i forgot to remove, it has been edited out

Answer (score 2):

**Blanket or low pillow**

Seat design is adapted to the use and requirements of the seat. A seat for a dog is radically different from a seat for humans.

Sitting down for a horse can mean two things. Either only the behind hits the seat, or the horse is laying down. A horse can definitely sit, which means the bottom touches the ground. I'm not an expert on horses, but sitting down on the bottom doesn't seem to be done for comfort. Laying down however is at times. For each the optimal height is ground level for a comfortable seating position. Otherwise the horse is halfway down or something. If the seat is raised for laying down the legs just hang there a little. Ever let your legs dangle straight down? Not a pleasant experience after a time, as it's not made for straight down dangling.

With the ground being the optimal height, it is a question what is best for sitting. As discussed before, sitting down doesn't seem comfortable for a longer period. Laying down seems fine, as a centaur's torso is in an upright position. The centaur can still use it's head and arms to do many tasks. At worst you need a height difference in standing and 'sitting' desks.

I understand that sitting on the ground isn't favourable to a seat. In nature humans often prefer to sit on at least a blanket. So I'm disregarding just sitting on the ground. A blanket, possibly slightly shaped, seems best. Maybe a very low big pillow. This is great, as it can be ergonomic, easy to move and even to take with you.

Then again we're designing a seat for a creature of which the lower half rarely sits or is Laying down. It sleeps standing up with a special system in it's legs! In addition, the centaur makeup should allow this with more prudence. How would the human half ever be able to comfortably lay down? Standing must already be ingrained in it's biology. Strictly speaking, a seat isn't required. If you really want some, a blanket or low pillow would be best.